# Sort Products in context doesnt update in my components

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I want to sort my products by lowest price, when i use 'sortByLowest' function, it works fine, i can see my products ordered.

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const ProductsContext = createContext({});

const ProductsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  console.log(products);

  const sortByLowest = () => {
    console.log(products);
    const sorted = products.sort((a, b) => a.cost - b.cost);
    setProducts(sorted);
    console.log(sorted);
  };

  return (
    <ProductsContext.Provider value={{ products, setProducts, sortByLowest }}>
      {children}
    </ProductsContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { ProductsProvider };
export default ProductsContext;
```

The problem is that it happends in my ProductsContext, but my component ProductList doesnt re-render to show my products ordered

```
import ProductList from "components/ProductsList";
import Banner from "components/Banner";
import Header from "components/Header";
import Sort from "components/Sort";
import { useContext } from "react";
import ProductsContext from "context/ProductsContext";

const Home = () => {
  const { products } = useContext(ProductsContext);

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Banner />
      <Sort products={products} />
      <ProductList products={products} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

I dont know why my products variable doesnt update in my components.

```
import ProductsContext from "context/ProductsContext";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { BtnSort, ContainerSort, Title } from "./styles";

const Sort = () => {
  const { sortByLowest } = useContext(ProductsContext);

  return (
    <ContainerSort>
      <Title>Sort By:</Title>
      <BtnSort>Most recent</BtnSort>
      <BtnSort onClick={sortByLowest}>Lowest price</BtnSort>
      <BtnSort>Highest price</BtnSort>
    </ContainerSort>
  );
};

export default Sort;
```

The last component is where i sort the products. I tried using this button on the same component, but doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

## Use React Hook called `useEffect`

Wrap your function `sortByLowest` with `useEffect` hook to re-render on state change.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const sortByLowest = () => {
    console.log(products);
    const sortedproducts = products.sort((a, b) => a.cost - b.cost);
    setProducts(sortedproducts);
    console.log(sortedproducts);
  };
  }, [products]);
}
```

Comment: i tried, but when i wrap my function, it only exist inside useEffect, i cant send this function to a component because isnt defined